# why does emplace_back need move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Test final {
public:
  Test(const std::string& s)
    : s_(s) {
    std::cout << "constructing: " << s_ << std::endl;
  }
#ifdef NO_MOVE
private:
  Test(const Test& t) = delete;
  Test(Test&& t) = delete;
#else
public:
  Test(const Test& t)
    : s_(t.s_) {
    std::cout << "copying: " << s_ << std::endl;
  };
  Test(Test&& t)
    : s_(std::move(t.s_)) {
    std::cout << "moving: " << s_ << std::endl;
  };
#endif
private:
  std::string s_;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Test> v;
  v.emplace_back("emplace_back");
}
```

When a move constructor is allowed, the following occurs:

```
[matt test] g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp && ./a.out
constructing: emplace_back
```

However, if the move constructor is removed:

```
[matt test] g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -DNO_MOVE && ./a.out
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = Test; _Args = {Test}]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:77:3:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<Test*>; _ForwardIterator = Test*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:119:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<Test*>; _ForwardIterator = Test*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:260:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<Test*>; _ForwardIterator = Test*; _Tp = Test]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:283:69:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = Test*; _ForwardIterator = Test*; _Allocator = std::allocator<Test>]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/vector.tcc:410:6:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_emplace_back_aux(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const char (&)[13]}; _Tp = Test; _Alloc = std::allocator<Test>]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/vector.tcc:102:4:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const char (&)[13]}; _Tp = Test; _Alloc = std::allocator<Test>]’
main.cpp:32:32:   required from here
main.cpp:14:3: error: ‘Test::Test(Test&&)’ is private
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/vector:63:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_construct.h:77:7: error: within this context
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_construct.h:77:7: error: use of deleted function ‘Test::Test(Test&&)’
main.cpp:14:3: error: declared here
```

But the `emplace_back` doesn't use the move constructor.  Why does the initialization require a move constructor in this instance?

Comment: Doing this with `gcc 4.7.2`

Comment: well, you are also defing out the the copy-ctor, emplace-back needs either a copy- or a move-ctor.

Comment: Wrong, it should need neither for the emplacement itself. However, for regrowing, `T` needs to be atleast `MoveConstructible`, which is, IIRC, also a general requirement for `std::vector`.

Comment: But why does `emplace_back` need a `copy` or `move` constructor?  It is supposed to be ['constructed in-place, i.e. no copy or move operations are performed'](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)

Comment: @Xeo what's wrong? emplace-back can cause the vector to regrow which needs a copy/move-ctor.

Comment: So it's the regrowing that needs the copy/move constructor.

Comment: guys, please add these comments as answers. i don't want to look like copying these comments when put my answer :(

Comment: @bamboon: I meant the inplace construction itself. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As specified in the comment after the question.  The `emplace_back` operator may need to reallocate the containers memory and as such the `vector` template type needs to be either copy or move constructable.

It's not the forwarding of the arguments that is the issue it is the allocating of memory for the new object.

Comment: Also remember about `noexcept` for move constructor, as it is not safe to move multiple elements not atomically.

Comment: Just for reference, this is called out in Table 101 of the C++11 standard, "For vector, T shall also be MoveInsertable into X".

Answer (score 1):

If there is no space in the vector then it should allocate new space and move everything there and to avoid copy of the resource contained or owned by the objects(inside vector) move is required

For vector of type `Test`

```
Test object(original)--->resource on heap
Test object(relocated with move constructor)------>resource on heap
Test object(relocated with copy constructor)------>copy of resource on heap
```