# Templates and universal references

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference, type-deduction

**I'm following a tutorial on creating an Entity Component Framework. It uses composition (an entity has a set of components).**

```
class Component
{
public:
    Entity* entity;

 //VIRTUAL VOID INITIALIZE, DRAW, UPDATE functions here
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Entity> m_pEntity;
};

class Entity
{
public:

//Add component function

    template <typename T, typename... TArgs>
    T& addComponent(TArgs&&... mArgs)
    {
        T* LComponent(new T(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)));
        LComponent->entity = this;
        std::unique_ptr<Component> uPtr{ LComponent };
        m_pComponents.emplace_back(std::move(uPtr));
        m_ComponentArray[getComponentTypeID<T>()] = LComponent;
        LComponent->ECS_init();
        return *LComponent;

    }
private:
    bool m_IsActive = true;
    std::vector <std::unique_ptr<Component>> m_pComponents;
    std::array<Component*, gMaxComponents> m_ComponentArray;
};
```

However, the author did not explain the logic behind well and I'm failing to understand the syntax of addComponent function. In particular:

- Why does it need to cast `uPtr` to a rvalue reference
  `m_pComponents.emplace_back(std::move(uPtr))` when it adds it to the vector

Comment: Considering that the `addComponent` doesn't return anything at all, the first point becomes moot. Otherwise (if you add an explicit `return` statement) the difference between returning an object by value or by reference is very related to a function taking an argument by value or by reference. So if you know that difference, you should understand the difference for the return type as well.

Comment: You are asking many questions at the same time in a single question. Multiple questions should, in general, be asked as multiple individual Stackoverflow questions. One question per question.

Comment: And as for `new T`... Well, if you had `new Component` instead, would that make more sense to you? `new T` allocates memory for an object of the type `T` and then constructs that object. It doesn't matter what the type `T` is, it behaves the same for *any* `T` (doesn't matter if it's `Component`, `std::vector<Component>` or even `int`).

Comment: Edited. I had omitted the return value. Sorry. As for the many questions, you're asking that I open 5 different threads with the same code? Wouldn't that be a bit absurd?

Comment: @Daniel "you're asking that I open 5 different threads with the same code? Wouldn't that be a bit absurd?" - No. If you are asking 5 different questions you should ask 5 questions, even if the code related to each one is the same. Stackoverflow is a Q/A site where you ask *one* specific question and get *one* specific answer. It is *not* a discussion forum, chat or a site where you can just ask unspecified broad "stuff". 1 question, 1 answer is the format here.

Comment: I am missing the definition for LComponent.

Comment: @Klaus I'm sorry if I sounded harsh. I do understand passing by ref vs value. I've read at least two beginner's books on that. I've been trying to get into the depths of Modern C++ and my question was rather related to passing by rval reference, not just any reference. Also its role in template type deduction and using std::forward.

Comment: In the case of "emplace_back(std::move(uPtr))" it simply is the idea of a unique pointer that there is only a unique instance which "owns" something. So for inserting to a vector the ownership must be "moved" into the vector. As this, std::move is used to achieve that. So std::move is technically a cast to && but also makes it readable as it moves the ownership. Common misunderstanding is, that people feel the "object" is moved which is never the case. It is simply about passing ownership.

Comment: @Klaus this is the kind of stuff I come here for. Thanks.  I already knew about the transfer of ownership. Std::move doesn't move anything, only transfers. But if I understand correctly, in this case uPtr owns the instance of Component, which in this case is LComponent? Then it transfers the resource to a pointer inside the vector? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: std::move did not transfer nor move, it only casts to &&. The function which takes a rvalue ref (&&) should implement the semantic for "take the ownership please!". In your case, you have: `std::vector <std::unique_ptr<Component>> m_pComponents;` So the pointers inside the vector have the unique ownership to `Component` objects. So you create with `new` a new object on the heap and pass the ownership by  `m_pComponents.emplace_back(std::move(uPtr));` to the vector. That `emplace_back( T&& )` will really take over ownership is convention and not guaranteed by the language itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why does emplace\_back need move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615872/why-does-emplace-back-need-move-constructor)

Comment: Kind of. Thanks. Also, thanks @Klaus for the elaborate response. Really helped me understand my question better. One last thing: why is it necessary to implement move semantics here. Is it just for performance reasons? A good day to you as well!

Comment: "why is it necessary to implement move semantics here". Because you want to move the ownership of the pointer to the new instance inside the vector. If you don't have move semantic, how you would guarantee that the new instance of the unique pointer is now and only inside the instance in the vector. It is important that the old instance is "invalid" after the operation. There is no need to use the && syntax in this case, as the designers of containers may also provide something like emplace_back_by_move(). But having a temporary in the call is now automated! Thats the benefit of && here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it need to cast `uPtr` to a rvalue reference
>   `m_pComponents.emplace_back(std::move(uPtr))` when it adds it to the
>   vector

This is because `uPtr` is of type `std::unique_ptr`. This type can not be copied! It can only be moved. This is to make sure that there is only one unique handle that has owndership for the pointer.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that std::unique_ptr requires move instead of copy. A good day to you, sir.

Comment: @Daniel if you could copy a "unique" pointer, it would be no more "unique"